# Creating flight joystick node with libusb

Tags: ros, usb, joystick, libusb

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm trying to get standart usb hid joystick values. Actually I already get the data through libusb and standart C compiler in Eclipse (linux platform). But I wanted to integrate it to ROS and make it a node(joystick_publisher). But I failed.

When I try to merge my existing and working usb code and basic node example in ROS tutorials to create a simple node, I got couple of errors that tells me it didn't realize libusb functions. I already set ros dependency in manifest.xml for libusb-dev but I think rosdep is not able to find it. Rosdep not able to find libusb even in command line.

According to your request I can share the necessery data. If there are other ways to do this job it would be appriciated. Thanks for all helps.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/33523/creating-flight-joystick-node-with-libusb/) by [cheour](https://answers.ros.org/users/2230/cheour/) on ROS Answers with karma: 18 on 2012-05-08

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Dustin](https://answers.ros.org/users/1938/dustin/) on 2012-05-08**:
Why do you believe that rosdep cannot find libusb-dev? Do you receive errors during compilation? If so, what are they?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS already has the ability to interact with joysticks through the [joystick_drivers](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joystick_drivers) stack. Specifically, check out the [joy](http://www.ros.org/wiki/joy) package.

---

Originally posted by [Dan Lazewatsky](https://answers.ros.org/users/173/dan-lazewatsky/) with karma: 9115 on 2012-05-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 4